# getting back to old commit in github

Tags: git, github

I am using github to store my code. I have committed a code which has errors and I am not able to correct it. Now I want to revert to earlier version of code which was working fine. Can someone please help me in getting back to old working code of mine.

Thanks
Pankaj

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume from the way you've asked your question you've already pushed your changes to Github.

You can use `git revert` to undo a commit. This doesn't modify repository history, rather, it commits a change that is the opposite of your broken revision.

If the commit that you want to remove is the latest one type

```
git revert HEAD
```

to undo it.

Replace `HEAD` with the identifier of the broken commit if it isn't the latest one. You can find the identifier in the output of `git log`.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the [online Git book](https://book.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Undoing-Things) to figure out what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not pushed it yet, then run

```
git reset HEAD
```

to undo. It removes the last commit.

Comment: I would rather type `git reset HEAD`, with lowercase 'r' in 'reset'. Git is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't pushed the bad commit to github yet, you can ammend the commit.

But if you've pushed it, I'll reccomend that you just manually undo the changes to fix the errors (most likely there was at leas some of the changes you do want to keep) and comment in the commit message that the previus commit had bugs (in case anyone is wondering)

See also [this page](http://christoph.ruegg.name/blog/2010/5/5/git-howto-revert-a-commit-already-pushed-to-a-remote-reposit.html) for ways of getting back.

Personally I prefer to look at the diff from previous commits using for instance `git log -p` or `git diff <goodCommit> <head>` to find the changes and correct them. If you don't mind having a documented history of your errors this is probably cleanest and easiest (while modifying the history may cause problems if others have already pulled you broken commit).